# SQL query with one-to-many relationship with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate a list of cart items with a query that relates through a line_items table. I've abstracted a simple example of my use case:

my expected result would look like this:

```
cart_id  cart_total shopper_id items                                                        payment_id
      1         345         34 [{"name":"egg","price:"39"}]                                 AS34gsdVSWET4
      2          54         45 [{"name":"biscut","price:"5"},{"name":"apple","price:"15"}]  JFHERHJE$Y#$H
```

given a schema and data like:

carts:

```
id  cart_total shopper_id
1   39         34
2   20         45
```

line_items:

```
id  cart_id    item_name item_price
1   1          egg       39
2   2          biscut     5
3   2          apple     15
```

payment:

```
id  cart_id payment_id
1   1       AS34gsdVSWET4
2   2       JFHERHJE$Y#$H
```

How to get all cart list and get a list of carts for particular `shopperId`?

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution using `json_build_object`:

```
SELECT c.id AS cart_id,
       c.cart_total,
       c.shopper_id,
       json_agg(
          json_build_object(
             'item_name', i.item_name,
             'item_price', i.item_price::text
          )
       ) AS items,
       p.payment_id
FROM carts AS c
   JOIN line_items AS i ON i.cart_id = c.id
   JOIN payment AS p ON p.cart_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.cart_total, c.shopper_id, p.payment_id;
```

Are you sure you want the price as string?

Comment: Not required, do we need to include all fields in GROUP BY?

Comment: Your query results:   
items: [{"egg":39}], but I need [{"item_name":"egg","item_price":39}]

Comment: That was easily fixed. Retain the `GROUP BY` items.